# High ambient value while loading OBJ file

Tags: graphics, glsl, loading, .obj

I'm loading OBJ file that has been exported from 3ds max. The material in .mat file has strange ambient value of (1, 1, 1):

```
newmtl crome
Ns 96.078423
Ni 1.500000
d 1.000000
Tf 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
illum 2
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Just take a look at example: Ka has all 1s.
How's to be with such a data?
I'm using standard Blinn-Phong illumination model described in appropriate wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

I've forgotten about light source ambient factor which in product with material ambient factor produces correct value.